# AWS lambda calling two differents SNS mixed up account ids

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have the follow sam template for a lambda that would call two SNS fifo:

```
Resources:
  MainFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: core.lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Policies:
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: !Select [ 5, !Split [ ":", !Ref SNSTopicARN ] ]
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: !Select [ 5, !Split [ ":", !Ref SNSTopicARN2 ] ]
```

But when SNSTopicARN and SNSTopicARN2 has a ARN with different userId it creates wrong resource like in SNSTopic2 is created something like:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:idAccountFromSNS1:SNS2.fifo",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

So ids would be mixed up.
is there some way to specify ARN in SNSPublishMessagePolicy or use another approach to avoid this ?

Comment: `idAccountFromSNS1` it's actually the account ID of the cloudformation stack.  The stack is being deployed to the same account that owns SNS1, correct?  The [SNSPublishMessagePolicy template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#sqs-publish-message-policy) does not appear to support cross account access, as it takes `TopicName` and uses the builtin references `${AWS::AccountId}` and `${AWS::Region}` to fill in the rest, so it won't work for this cross account purpose.

Comment: @erik258 I see. Would there be some alternative ?

Comment: Afaik, the SAM SNSPublishMessagePolicy is a convenience template for creating policies allowing you to publish to a topic in the *same* account as the function is being deployed. You will probably have to create the cross-account equivalent (with the ARN into the other account) of this policy statement explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-sam-template-permissions:

> For the Policies property, enter any combination of the following:
>
> - The name of an AWS managed policy
> - The name of an AWS SAM policy template
> - An inline policy document

so you should be able to add something to the policies that looks like this:

```
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Sid: PublishToSNS
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - sns:Publish
          Resource:
          - !Ref SNSTopicARN
          - !Ref SNSTopicARN2
```